# Entity Framework Not Showing Database

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-4, sql-server-2008-r2, code-first

Working with Code First feature of Entity Framework 4.1 using an ASP.NET MVC 3 project.

However the database (SQL Server 2008 R2) does not automatically create the table mapping on application startup. Any ideas on how to make it do so?

```
using System;
using System.Data.Entity;
namespace MvcMovie.Models { 
public class Movie { 
    public int ID { get; set; } 
    public string Title { get; set; } 
    public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; } 
    public string Genre { get; set; } 
    public decimal Price { get; set; } 
}
```

Also there is this database context class

```
public class MovieDBContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Movie> Movies { get; set; }
} 
}
```

In global.asax file

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}
}
```

Kindly help?? I am a beginner? Even you could suggest some reading material for asp.net it would be of great help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a [good overview](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application).  You can use a config entry:

```
<entityFramework>
  <contexts>
    <context type="ContosoUniversity.DAL.SchoolContext, ContosoUniversity">
      <databaseInitializer type="ContosoUniversity.DAL.SchoolInitializer, ContosoUniversity" />
    </context>
  </contexts>
  <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
    <parameters>
      <parameter value="v11.0" />
    </parameters>
  </defaultConnectionFactory>
  <providers>
    <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
  </providers>
</entityFramework>
```

Or set it up via [code as mentioned here](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/article.php/c19999/Understanding-Database-Initializers-in-Entity-Framework-Code-First.htm):

```
Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<BlogContext>());
using (var db = new BlogContext())
{
    db.Database.Initialize(false);
    ...
}
```